# FullCalendar Angular 13 error when importing npm library

Tags: npm, fullcalendar, angular13

I have an npm library which imports Angular FullCalendar v5 and everything works fine there. When i try to import my project library to another project and try access the full calendar frontend I got a warning and a message error in my browser console:

```
 - Warning: main.js:7358 Unknown option 'default'
 - Error: core.mjs:6476 ERROR TypeError: Language ID should be string or object.
    at new DateTimeFormat (<anonymous>)
    at buildNativeFormattingFunc (main.js:1218)
    at NativeFormatter.buildFormattingFunc (main.js:1211)
    at NativeFormatter.buildFormattingFunc (main.js:1009)
    at NativeFormatter.format (main.js:1154)
    at NativeFormatter.formatRange (main.js:1169)
    at DateEnv.formatRange (main.js:3984)
    at CalendarDataManager.buildTitle (main.js:6909)
    at CalendarDataManager.buildTitle (main.js:1009)
    at CalendarDataManager.updateData (main.js:7113)
```

I can't figure it out why but i know it's in this line of code at main.js (@fullcalendar/common/main.js)
Line 1218 -> `var normalFormat = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(context.locale.codes, standardDateProps);` The error is that the variable context.locale.codes is undefined.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I've just had the same error. Not that I was importing a project library of my own but I was importing the Fullcalendar library (from node_modules). I had enabled localization using the `locale` property of the calendar options but I always got this error `Language ID should be string or object`.

Two things was wrong:

1. I was importing the locale code incorrectly which resulted in this error. The current version of Fullcalendar (6.0.0) has all its locale code under `@fullcalendar/core/locales`.
2. I was using dynamic import like this: `import("@fullcalendar/core/locales/da")` and it worked fine but I had to access the `default` property of the exported object. Using async/await syntax it becomes:

   const localeModule = await import("@fullcalendar/core/locales/da");

   const calendar = new Calendar(someElement, {
   (...),
   locale: localeModule.default

   });

Not directly answering your question but it sounds like you're using locale, too, and your other project is importing your project library in a way that makes the `default` property of the module containing the locale code undefined.